# What does "He was the assistant wardrobe man on Spartacus" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "He was the assistant wardrobe man on Spartacus" mean?

Source: http://www.tzr.io/yarn-clip/e5009257-aba5-45ca-8ebc-38031b40b28b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a movie, TV show, or theatrical performance, the person who is responsible for looking after all of the clothing, uniforms, jewelry, etc., that are worn by the actors, is usually called the Wardrobe Supervisor. This person may have one or two people to assist them; they are called Wardrobe Assistants (or sometime Assistant Dressers).

So "He was the assistant wardrobe man on Spartacus", simply means that the man they are talking about worked as the Wardrobe Assistant during filming of the movie (or possibly the television series) Spartacus.

Answer (score 1):

Spartacus is a movie from the 60's.

So, it means, that "he" was assistant to the person in charge of the wardrobe at the production site of the movie Spartacus.

Without context (and considering Seinfeld being a comedy) I am not sure, if they mean the costume department or really just the wardrobe in the studio. But I would assume the former.